# How to subscribe to a topic in flutter FCM?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm a new one in a flutter and in my app, I need to implement FCM with global or with a topic subscription. I successfully implemented the FCM with device token but need to send a notification to all device. how can we fix this?

Answer (score 44):

You can use subscribeToTopic to send a notification to all devices on login success or somewhere where you want to subscribe.
**sample code:**

```
FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

  void fcmSubscribe() {
    firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('TopicToListen');
  }

  void fcmUnSubscribe() {
    firebaseMessaging.unsubscribeFromTopic('TopicToListen');
  }
```

Test the topic subscription by using firebase console to send the notification to a topic that the device is listening by choosing the topic in target

Comment: While calling subscribeToTopic got java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:  FirebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic(Unknown Source).

Comment: is there any way to do that on flutter web

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery I haven't tried out web part, I hope someone can can answer this.

Comment: Can you please update the answer to match the current version of flutter

Comment: I had to change this to `FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic` to avoid the 'NoSuchMethod' error

Answer (score 11):

I could do it using the following code:

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('TopicToListen');
```

Answer (score 2):

For web version in flutter you need to call the api for topic

```
    Uri.parse('https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/'+_token+'/rel/topics/'+topic),
            headers: <String, String>{
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization':
                  'key=YOUR_FCM_KEY'
            };
```

token is the firebase generated token

Comment: can you provide some more information on where to put this and how to use it? thx

Comment: This is api call which you can call single time when you app starts